# Why does GHCI get "stuck" in an error state after an error?

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad

First of all, my apologies for the non-descriptive title. Since I have no idea what's actually going on I can't really make it any more specific.

Now for my question. I have implemented the following snippet for problem 23 of the [99 Haskell problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/21_to_28), which should randomly select `n` items from a list:

```
rndSelect' :: RandomGen g => [a] -> Int -> g -> ([a], g)
rndSelect' _ 0 gen = ([], gen)
rndSelect' [] _ _ = error "Number of items requested is larger than list"
rndSelect' xs n gen = ((xs !! i) : rest, gen'')
                    where (i, gen') = randomR (0, length xs - 1) gen
                          (rest, gen'') = (rndSelect' (removeAt xs i) (n - 1) gen')

rndSelectIO' :: [a] -> Int -> IO [a]
rndSelectIO' xs n = getStdRandom $ rndSelect' xs n

removeAt :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
removeAt xs n
  | length xs <= n || n < 0 = error "Index out of bounds"
  | otherwise = let (ys, zs) = splitAt n xs
                    in ys ++ (tail zs)
```

Now when I load this in `ghci` this works correctly for valid arguments:

```
*Main> rndSelectIO' "asdf" 2 >>= putStrLn 
af
```

However, strange things happen when I use an index that is out of bounds:

```
*Main> rndSelectIO' "asdf" 5 >>= putStrLn
dfas*** Exception: Number of items requested is larger than list
*Main> rndSelectIO' "asdf" 2 >>= putStrLn
*** Exception: Number of items requested is larger than list
```

As you can see, the following 2 (for me) unexpected things happen:

1. Instead of directly giving an error it first print a permutation of the input.
2. After it has given an error once, it won't execute at all anymore.

I suspect that 1. has to do with lazy evaluation, but I have absolutely no clue why 2. happens. What's going on here?

Comment: Each line in the interactive session is inside the same implicit `do` statement, which never ends, so every line passes its result to the next.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `getStdRandom` function basically looks up a `StdGen` value in a global variable, runs some function on it, puts the new seed back into the global variable, and returns the result to the caller.

If the function in question returns with an error, that error gets put into the global variable. Now all attempts to use this global variable will throw an exception. (I *told* you global variables are evil! `;-)`)

Try calling `getStdGen` manually yourself. It will either print out the current random seed, or throw an exception. If it throws an exception... there's your problem.

I believe you can use `setStdGen` to reset the thing.

Comment: So it's a laziness problem right? `getStdRandom` should not be able to put back an error in `StdGen`.

Comment: @mariop Arguably allowing a single global variable for this is a hack in the first place (e.g., thread safety could be threatened). But yeah, I guess you could argue it should do some hoopy thing to avoid reinserting an exception into the global variable...

Comment: How is this dealt with in real world applications? Does everyone initialize it's own random generator all the time? And is this a deliberate design decision, or was it an oversight not to catch errors in `getStdRandom`?

Comment: You don't generally ever use `error` in real world applications. You would return a `Maybe` or `Either` value instead. In real applications you also usually use some other randomness source than `StdGen`.

Comment: Ideally yes, you manage your own random seed rather than relying on a hidden global variable shared between all code in the entire program. (And `System.Random` generally isn't very performant; there are other libraries for that, implementing Mersenne-twister or MWC or whatever.)